# Cannot convert pdf to html using Pdf2Html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I am using rails 4. I have been able to convert doc file to pdf using docsplit gem. Now i want to convert this pdf file to html and display it. How can I do this? Right now i have tried with Pdf2Html gem, while calling this(like below) for conversion it will throw an error like "can't dup NilClass".

```
Pdf2Html.convert "#{pdf_file_path}", {:dest_dir=>"/project/", :zoom=> 1.5}
```

Also I have tried with below command, then i got an error like "Can't find pdf2htmlex executable in PATH"

```
Kristin.convert("#{pdf_file_path}", "document.html")
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What's the point of converting a doc file to pdf if you ultimately want it embedded in an html file?

Comment: The problem is actually written in the error, the `pdf2htmlex` binary is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pdf2htmlEX in you local system, because kristin using the pdf2htmlEx library. so check weather that library already installed in your system or not.